# MySQL ORDER BY extremely slow - even with indexes

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, innodb

I have got a quite complex query with many joins which runs very well without ordering. But as soon as i try to order by any of my fields it is executing extremely slow and takes about 30 seconds to complete.

**Here's the query:**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE *
FROM et_order

INNER JOIN et_order_type ON et_order.type_id = et_order_type.id
INNER JOIN et_order_data ON et_order.id = et_order_data.order_id
INNER JOIN et_user et_user_consultant ON et_order.user_id_consulting = et_user_consultant.id
INNER JOIN et_customer ON et_order.customer_id = et_customer.id
INNER JOIN et_appointment ON et_order.appointment_id = et_appointment.id
INNER JOIN et_order_status order_status ON et_order.order_status_id = order_status.id
INNER JOIN et_status glass_r_status ON et_order_data.status_id_glass_r = glass_r_status.id
INNER JOIN et_status glass_l_status ON et_order_data.status_id_glass_l = glass_l_status.id

ORDER BY et_order.id DESC 

LIMIT 50
```

The original query is even bigger and has various WHERE operations as well, but even the base query without any condition is unreasonably slow. When I remove the ORDER BY et_order.id DESC the query takes about 0.01 secs to fetch.

In my original query, I select every single field I need separately - just changed it to 'SELECT *' now for better readability of the statement.

**Explain Select gives the following result:**

```
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table              | type   | possible_keys                                                                 | key         | key_len | ref                                     | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | et_customer        | ALL    | PRIMARY                                                                       | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                    | 59750 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | et_order           | ref    | PRIMARY,customer_id,appointment_id,user_id_consulting,order_status_id,type_id | customer_id | 4       | eyetool.et_customer.id                  |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | et_user_consultant | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                       | PRIMARY     | 4       | eyetool.et_order.user_id_consulting     |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | et_appointment     | ref    | PRIMARY                                                                       | PRIMARY     | 8       | eyetool.et_order.appointment_id         |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | et_order_data      | ref    | status_id_glass_l,status_id_glass_r,order_id                                  | order_id    | 5       | eyetool.et_order.id                     |     1 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | et_order_type      | ALL    | PRIMARY                                                                       | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                    |     4 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | glass_l_status     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                       | PRIMARY     | 4       | eyetool.et_order_data.status_id_glass_l |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | order_status       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id                                                                    | PRIMARY     | 4       | eyetool.et_order.order_status_id        |     1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | glass_r_status     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                       | PRIMARY     | 4       | eyetool.et_order_data.status_id_glass_r |     1 |                                 |
+----+-------------+--------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I don't really understand is why explain select says it does not use any key for et_order_type. Maybe because it is not needed since there are only 4 rows in it!?

But there is an index on type_id in et_order:   KEY `type_id` (`type_id`)

I've added a (single) **INDEX** for every key I am using for joining and ordering. Could this be the problem? Do I need to create combined indexes?

The Table contains about 200.000 datasets in et_order and et_order_data, 60.000 in et_customer, 150.000 in et_apointments. Other contents are negligible.

When i just join et_order_data and et_order_type, it also takes very long and explain select still says key NULL for et_order_type:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE *
FROM et_order

INNER JOIN et_order_type ON et_order.type_id = et_order_type.id
INNER JOIN et_order_data ON et_order.id = et_order_data.order_id

ORDER BY et_order.id DESC 

LIMIT 50

+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------+----------+---------+---------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys   | key      | key_len | ref                 | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------+----------+---------+---------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | et_order      | ALL  | PRIMARY,type_id | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                | 162007 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | et_order_data | ref  | order_id        | order_id | 5       | eyetool.et_order.id |      1 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | et_order_type | ALL  | PRIMARY         | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                |      4 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+-----------------+----------+---------+---------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

The **Table structure** for et_order and et_order_type can be reviewed here: http://pastebin.com/PED6Edyx

Any tips to optimize my query?

**I tried ordering in a subquery like:**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE *
FROM (SELECT * FROM et_order ORDER BY et_order.id DESC) as et_order
INNER JOIN et_order_type ON et_order.type_id = et_order_type.id
...
```

This was very quick, but does not help at all, because i have to do the ordering not only on et_order, but also on fields of the joined tables.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Update:**

Strange, when i change every inner join to a left one it works like a charme...

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE *
FROM et_order
LEFT JOIN et_order_type ON et_order.type_id = et_order_type.id
LEFT JOIN et_order_data ON et_order.id = et_order_data.order_id
LEFT JOIN et_user et_user_consultant ON et_order.user_id_consulting = et_user_consultant.id
LEFT JOIN et_customer ON et_order.customer_id = et_customer.id
LEFT JOIN et_appointment ON et_order.appointment_id = et_appointment.id
LEFT JOIN et_order_status order_status ON et_order.order_status_id = order_status.id
LEFT JOIN et_status glass_r_status ON et_order_data.status_id_glass_r = glass_r_status.id
LEFT JOIN et_status glass_l_status ON et_order_data.status_id_glass_l = glass_l_status.id

ORDER BY et_order.id DESC LIMIT 50

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Any time you see "Using temporary; Using filesort" on tens of thousands of rows you know you're going to have a bad day.

Comment: 59750 | Using temporary; Using filesort --- That's what's killing it.

Comment: Can you get what you need without sorting the results-- but instead have the data ordered on the application level?

Comment: @DudeSolutions Sorting on application level would be to much, there are about 200.000 results to be sorted..

Comment: @tadman Yes, filesort is pain, but how can i handle it?

Comment: can u please tell me which version of mysql you are using?

Comment: @tadman: With aggregate functions such as MAX() and MIN(). They perform better than filesort. Rather than completely rewriting your query myself, I would advise to try hammering down a range of indices with these two functions in a subquery to narrow down your dataset. From there, you will still use filesort--but the dataset will be much more manageable and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE *
FROM et_order
INNER JOIN et_order_type ON et_order.type_id = et_order_type.id
INNER JOIN et_order_data ON et_order.id = et_order_data.order_id
INNER JOIN et_user et_user_consultant ON et_order.user_id_consulting = et_user_consultant.id
INNER JOIN et_customer FORCE INDEX(et_customer.id) ON et_order.customer_id = et_customer.id
INNER JOIN et_appointment ON et_order.appointment_id = et_appointment.id
INNER JOIN et_order_status order_status ON et_order.order_status_id = order_status.id
INNER JOIN et_status glass_r_status ON et_order_data.status_id_glass_r = glass_r_status.id
INNER JOIN et_status glass_l_status ON et_order_data.status_id_glass_l = glass_l_status.id
ORDER BY et_order.id DESC LIMIT 50
```

Comment: This produces an sql error.

When i try 

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * 
FROM et_order
FORCE INDEX ( customer_id ) 
INNER JOIN et_order_type ON et_order.type_id = et_order_type.id
...

it takes about 120 seconds to complete :-(